# Sync MySQL table to PostgreSQL with push from MySQL

Tags: linux, mysql, postgresql

I have a `MySQL` database running behind strict firewalls, and only listening on `localhost` - not even `127.0.0.1`.

I have a remote `PostgreSQL` which I would like to have a `synced` copy of a `table` from the `MySQL` database.

The server running the `MySQL` database is able to connect to the `PostgreSQL` database, as outgoing connections are allowed.

Is it possible to have the `MySQL` database sync via push a table to the remote `PostgreSQL` and keeping it in `sync` in near-realtime?

I've looked at the `foreign data wrappers` for `PostgreSQL` but they sort of work the other way around, and doesn't store a `replica` locally.

Cannot find if there's any `foreign data wrapper` for `MySQL` which can `insert`/`update`/`delete` into a `PostgreSQL`?

Answer (score 1):

Not a sysadmin solution/answer, but if only for one table, I would suggest building a small service that sync from the mysql to the postgree db that table.

I did that for two mysql database in the past, but I had to add a table field to know if the field was sync'ed.

Comment: My challenge is that fields can be updated, so I need to keep track of which field has been updated, created, deleted etc. to know what to sync. And also need to do it almost realtime?

Comment: Like I wrote, you need a field in the table that keep track if the record need to be synced, but it's a homemade solution.. can't use mysql on both side ? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned the OS but assuming a Linux system, you could create SSH tunnel, something like: `ssh root@<HOSTNAME> -L 5432:localhost:5432` and try [pg_chameleon](http://www.pgchameleon.org/):

> pg_chameleon is a MySQL to PostgreSQL replica system written in Python
>   3. The tool can connect to the mysql replication protocol and replicate the data changes in PostgreSQL. Whether the user needs to
>   setup a permanent replica between MySQL and PostgreSQL or perform an
>   engine migration, pg_chamaleon is the perfect tool for the job.